# Drop down menu without JMenuBar

Tags: swing, button, drop-down-menu, popupmenu, jmenubar

Is there a way to implement drop down button in Java, but without implementing `JMenuBar`?
I need to import a button with popup menu. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not have a button on focusGained / button clicked and show a JPopMenu underneath the button?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, not sure why you didn't make that an answer...

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidKroukamp stated, a JPopupMenu should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
    import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
    import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

    public class MenuButton extends JToggleButton {

        JPopupMenu popup;

        public MenuButton(String name, JPopupMenu menu) {
            super(name);
            this.popup = menu;
            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    JToggleButton b = MenuButton.this;
                    if (b.isSelected()) {
                        popup.show(b, 0, b.getBounds().height);
                    } else {
                        popup.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });
            popup.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {
                @Override
                public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
                @Override
                public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                    MenuButton.this.setSelected(false);
                }
                @Override
                public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
            });
        }
    }
```